# react router, converting from older version

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm tying to convert old react router code.

I cannot find a place that explains how to update old react router code.

How the code below can be translated using "react-router": "^4.2.0" ?

Sample code from app-client.js :

```
var Router = require('react-router');
var Route = Router.Route;
var DefaultRoute = Router.DefaultRoute;

var routes = (
    <Route handler={APP}>
        <DefaultRoute handler={Audience} />
        <Route name="speaker" path="speaker" handler={Speaker}></Route>
        <Route name="board" path="board" handler={Board}></Route>
    </Route>
);

Router.run(routes, function(handler) {
    ReactDOM.render(<APP />, document.getElementById('react-container'));
});
```

Sample code from APP.js :

```
var Router = require('react-router');
var RouteHandler = Router.RouteHandler;

var APP = createReactClass({
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <Header title={this.state.title} status={this.state.status} />
                <RouteHandler />
            </div>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = APP;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use your search skills:) duck duck go! "react Router Migration"

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/guides/migrating.md

https://codeburst.io/react-router-v4-unofficial-migration-guide-5a370b8905a

First two:)

Comment: Trying, trying...   Why for instance `<Route path="/" component={Board} /> `  can load the Board component, but not this : `<Route path="/board" component={Board} />` if I visit /board ?

Comment: Try add ‘exact’ to the route

Comment: Tried that, no help.   I get "Cannot GET /board".

Comment: Basically, what I want is displaying a content based on a route, like with `<RouteHandler />` in APP.js